# Mean and variance of $p(x)=\lambda x^{\lambda−1}$

Tags: probability, statistics

$$p(x)=\lambda x^{\lambda−1}$$
$$ 0<x<1, \lambda>0$$

Hi I'm studying statistics at the moment and I came upon a question that asked me how to solve for the **mean and variance** of this distribution.
I don't think it's the Poisson distribution but I could be wrong. Could it also be the sum of an infinite series?

What does the λ mean in this context?

Furthermore, I was wondering whether there is a difference between the inequality signs, ≥ and > when taking into account of the restrictions of this distribution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

Comment: Do you know the formula for finding the mean of a random variable when you know it's PDF?

Comment: As for $<$ versus $\le$, normally it wouldn't matter for a continuous random variable, but if $\lambda<1$, then the PDF wouldn't be defined at $x=0$.

Comment: "Solve for" is the wrong term. You can _find_ or _evaluate_ or _determine_ the mean and variance, but "solve for" means something else.

Answer (score 2):

"Solve for" is the wrong term. You can find or evaluate or determine the mean and variance, but "solve for" means something else. If you're given $v+w=8,$ you can *solve* that *for* $w,$ getting $w=8-x.$

With cumulative distribution functions defined piecewise, care must be taken in distinguishing between $\le$ and $<,$ but with densities defined piecewise it's not so important because changing the value of the function at just one point does not alter its integral over any set. I prefer to use the strict inequality in that context, since the weak inequality would make it appear that the value at an individual point matters.

Rather than saying "the mean and variance of $p(x)=\cdots,$ it is more precise to say "the mean and variance of the probability distribution whose density is $p(x)=\cdots.$

The mean is $\mu = \int_0^1 xp(x)\,dx.$

The variance is $\sigma^2 =\int_0^1 (x-\mu)^2p(x)\,dx.$